# JPA custom query returning only some values

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I did some tests and I couldn't be able to find the problem.

I'm doing some custom queries which I need to return only some data from my database, the problem is that it returns only some column's values.

[My query should return this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSjMi.png)

But it returns only this:

```
[
    {
        "nome": "ALAN ",
        "empresa": "data",
        "ultimaSaida": null,
        "grupoUsuarios": null,
        "epc": null,
        "areaControleAtual": null
    },
    {
        "nome": "ALEXANDRE ",
        "empresa": "data",
        "ultimaSaida": null,
        "grupoUsuarios": null,
        "epc": null,
        "areaControleAtual": null
    },
    {
        "nome": "BRUNO ",
        "empresa": "data",
        "ultimaSaida": null,
        "grupoUsuarios": null,
        "epc": null,
        "areaControleAtual": null
    }
```

Only the field `nome`, `epc (null is correct)` and `empresa` are okay.

I believe that the problem is in my custom query, but I don't know what is wrong.

My custom query:

```
public interface EmployeesRepository extends JpaRepository<Employees, Integer> {

   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USRAPP.ACESSO_LISTA WHERE 'FAB' = SUBSTR(area_controle_atual, 1, 3)",  nativeQuery = true)
    List<EmployeesNecessaryData> findEmployeesByFactory();

}
```

My interface:

```
public interface EmployeesNecessaryData {
    String getNome();

    String getUltimaSaida();

    String getEpc();

    String getAreaControleAtual();

    String getGrupoUsuarios();

    String getEmpresa();


}
```

The `employees` class:

```
@Table(name = "ACESSO_LISTA", schema = "USRAPP")
public class Employees {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID_USUARIO")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "NOME")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "EMPRESA")
    private String empresa;
    @Column(name = "ULTIMA_SAIDA")
    private String ultimaSaida;
    @Column(name = "AREA_CONTROLE_ATUAL")
    private String areaControleAtual;
    @Column(name = "GRUPO_USUARIOS")
    private String grupoUsuarios;
    @Column(name = "EPC")
    private String epc;

    public Employees(String nome, String areaControleAtual, String empresa, String grupoUsuarios, String ultimaSaida) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.areaControleAtual = areaControleAtual;
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.grupoUsuarios = grupoUsuarios;
        this.ultimaSaida = ultimaSaida;
    }

    public Employees(String nome, String empresa) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public String getUltimaSaida() {
        return ultimaSaida;
    }

    public void setUltimaSaida(String ultimaSaida) {
        this.ultimaSaida = ultimaSaida;
    }

    public String getAreaControleAtual() {
        return areaControleAtual;
    }

    public void setAreaControleAtual(String areaControleAtual) {
        this.areaControleAtual = areaControleAtual;
    }

    public String getGrupoUsuarios() {
        return grupoUsuarios;
    }

    public void setGrupoUsuarios(String grupoUsuarios) {
        this.grupoUsuarios = grupoUsuarios;
    }

    public String getEpc() {
        return epc;
    }

    public void setEpc(String epc) {
        this.epc = epc;
    }
}
```

My endpoint call, where returns the JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<EmployeesNecessaryData> startList(@RequestParam("sector") String sector) {

      return employeesRepository.findEmployeesByFactory();          

}
```

I thank in advance.

Comment: You are using SQL not JPQL an it will only map columns that directly match the property names. Your property is named differently than the column in your DB and thus doesn't show up.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum! I think got it what you said. So I need to change my query to JPQL format, correct?

Comment: Or properly include the fields you want and use aliases for the column (`select nome, ULTIMA_SAIDA as ultimaSaida FROM ....` something like that.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you so much! I finally understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

- Try this query
- change below,  how you need
- when you publish new question describe everything because it will
  help to help you

```
public interface EmployeesRepository extends JpaRepository<Employees, Integer> {

   @Query(
          value = 
             "select c from  c.USRAPP.ACESSO_LISTA where c.'FAB' = SUBSTRING(c.area_controle_atual, 1, 3)")
    List<EmployeesNecessaryData> findEmployeesByFactory();


    }
```